# Is this encryption method secure?

Tags: aes, pbkdf2, c++

I developed an application in C++ using Crypto++ to encrypt information and store the file in the hard drive. I use an integrity string to check if the password entered by the user is correct. Can you please tell me if the implementation generates a secure file? I am new to the world of the cryptography and I made this program with what I read.

```
string integrity = "ImGood"
string plaintext = integrity + string("some text");
byte password[pswd.length()]; // The password is filled somewhere else
byte salt[SALT_SIZE]; // SALT_SIZE is 32
byte key[CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH];
byte iv[CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE];

CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool rnd;
rnd.GenerateBlock(iv, CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE);
rnd.GenerateBlock(salt, SALT_SIZE);

CryptoPP::PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC<CryptoPP::SHA512> gen;
gen.DeriveKey(key, CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH, 32,
              password, pswd.length(),
              salt, SALT_SIZE,
              256);

CryptoPP::StringSink* sink = new CryptoPP::StringSink(cipher);
CryptoPP::Base64Encoder* base64_enc = new CryptoPP::Base64Encoder(sink);
CryptoPP::CFB_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption cfb_encryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH, iv);
CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter* aes_enc = new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(cfb_encryption, base64_enc);
CryptoPP::StringSource source(plaintext, true, aes_enc);

sstream out;
out << iv << salt << cipher;
```

The information in the string stream "out" is then written to a file. Another thing is that I don't know what the "purpose" parameter in the derivation function means, I'm guessing it is the desired length of the key so I put 32, but I'm not sure and I can't find anything about it in the Crypto++ manual.

Any opinion, suggestion or mistake pointed out is appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: At first glance, your "integrity" check is completely broken (it only at all protects the integrity of the first six bytes of each block AFAICT, and even then only very weakly). Either use an authenticated cipher mode (e.g., GCM, EAX, CCFB) or derive a second key (that's what the "purpose" parameter is for; allowing you to produce multiple keys for different purposes from the same inputs) and use it to compute an HMAC over the ciphertext and IV.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephen. I thought that if the integrity string was decrypted correctly, then the entire message was meaning that the password was correct. But I'll read upon authentication and those modes that you mentioned. Lastly, so if I set the purpose to 32, the code generates key number 32? Thanks again.

Comment: The value of the `purpose` parameter is completely arbitrary, as long as it's consistent within whatever context you're using it in. I'm curious: what, exactly, led you to believe that your approach would ensure the integrity the ciphertext?

Comment: I think I explained incorrectly what I mean with integrity string. I use it to see if the user wrote the correct password, if the password is correct, then the decrypted plaintext will be "ImGood" + "text to be secure". If the bytes corresponding to that string aren't equal to "ImGood" then the password was wrong. At the moment I don't know about a metho to verify the password but I'm still reading about it. Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for code review, and should have been moved to codereview.stackexchange.com instead of here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A file can be "secure" only if you define what you mean by "secure".

Usually, you will be interested in two properties:

- **Confidentiality**: the data that is encrypted shall remain unreadable to attackers; revealing the plaintext data requires knowledge of a specific secret.
- **Integrity**: any alteration of the data should be reliably detected; attackers shall not be able to modify the data in any way (even "blindly") without the modification being noticed by whoever decrypts the data.

Your piece of code, apparently, fulfils confidentiality (to some extent) but not integrity. Your string called "`integrity`" is a misnomer: it is *not* an integrity check. Its role is apparently to detect *accidental* password mistakes, not attacks; thus, it would be less confusing if that string was called `passwordVerifier` instead. An attacker can alter any bit beyond the first 48 bits without the decryption process noticing anything.

Adding integrity (the genuine thing) requires the use of a [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code). Combining encryption and a MAC securely is [subject to subtleties](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac); therefore, it is recommended to use for encryption and MAC an [authenticated encryption mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) which does both, and does so securely (i.e. that specific combination was explicitly reviewed by hordes of cryptographers). Usual recommended AE modes include [GCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) and [EAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode).

An important point to note is that, in a context where integrity matters, data cannot be processed before having been verified. This has implications for big files: if your huge file is adorned with a single MAC (whether "manually" or as part of an AE mode), then you must first verify the complete file before beginning to do anything with the plaintext data. This does not work well with streamed processing (e.g. if playing a huge video). A workaround is to split the data into individual chunks, each with its own MAC, but then some care must be taken about the ordering of chunks (attackers could try to remove, duplicate or reorder chunks): things become complex. Complexity, on a general basis, is bad for security.

There are contexts where integrity does not matter. For instance, if your attack model is "the attacker steals the laptop", then you only have to care about confidentiality. However, if the attack model is "the attacker steals the laptop, modifies a few files, and puts it back in my suitcase without me noticing", then integrity matters: the attacker could plant a modification in the file, and infer parts of the secret itself based on your external behaviour when you next access the file.

For confidentiality, you use [CFB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_feedback_.28CFB.29), which is a bit old-style, but not wrong. For the password-to-key transform, you use PBKDF2, which is fine; the iteration count, though, is quite low: you use 256. Typical values are 20000 or more. The [theory](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) is that you should make *actual performance measures* to set this count to as high a value as you can tolerate: a higher value means slower processing, both for you and for the attacker, so you ought to crank that up (depending on your patience).

---

**Mandatory warning:** you are in the process of defining your own crypto, which is a path fraught with perils. Most people who do that produce weak systems, and that includes trained cryptographers; in fact, being a trained cryptographer does not mean that you know how to define a secure protocol, but rather that you know better than defining your own protocol. You are thus *highly encouraged* to rely on an existing protocol (or format), rather than making your own. I suggest [OpenPGP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880), with (for instance) [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/) as support library. Even if you need for some reason (e.g. licence issues) to reimplement the format, using a standard format is still a good idea: it avoids introducing weaknesses, it promotes interoperability, and it can be tested against existing systems.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write such an answer. Stephen Touset also suggested to use an authentication mode so I replaced the CFB implementation with one using EAX and now Crypto++ does the authentication which fails if the password is not correct or if the integrity was compromised. I am now reading about OpenPGP and GnuPG. Thanks again.